# Can the technologies input fields on the careers profile page be a little more user friendly?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I regularly update my careers profile to reflect my current likes and dislikes.

The input fields are pretty wide already, but my 'likes' input field is filled up and it's a hassle to add more.

[image]

Currently, I have "too many" likes and to add another I have to select an existing one and from there mash the arrow keys to navigate to the back of the line to add one. This is taking longer each time I add one.

I'm aware of the tooltip that says

[image]

but I have many likes and I can't and don't want to decide on a top 5, I'd much rather list them all.

---

**Suggestion**
Change it so when you click on an input field, it automatically jumps to the back of the list, making it easy to add new ones.

Comment: Related on MSE (apparently [meta-tag:careers] questions should go there): [Make the 'Technologies' tag editor multi-line](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242647/167646)

Comment: Yeah same thing. Thanks for the link. I searched for existing questions but had a hard time coming up with a good query, and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Stijn I was going to delete this, but maybe it's better if I leave it up for just a bit, to attract some attention to your question from 2014.

Comment: That's fine. I could put a bounty on the MSE question but I don't really bother with bounties anymore.

Comment: I just thought it was supposed to mirror the 5 tag limit of questions.  If you need more than 5 tags to describe your absolute favorite things, then there are freeform intro and background fields to go into however much detail you want.

Comment: @davidism I suppose that's true. Although it doesn't say "absolute favourite things", it says "likes"

Comment: I tried to think of it as "describe yourself in five (ten if you include dislikes) words or less."  Yes, you are obviously more interesting than 5 tags, but it's an exercise in brevity.

Comment: @davidism I see.  I can work with that. Thanks

Comment: "select an existing one and from there mash the arrow keys to navigate to the back of the line to add one" FYI, most keyboards have an `End` key you can use instead of mashing the arrow keys to get to the end of a line.

Comment: @Ajedi32 some do, some don't. Macs for example don't have an end button afaik

Comment: @TimCastelijns Really? Don't they at least have some substitute though? (Maybe a key combo?) I couldn't imagine writing code without `Home` and `End`. Then again though, I'm not really a Mac user.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I know right. It's what I miss most when working on a mac. No home or end button is a pain in the butt